# Completely remove Gnome Desktop / revert splash logo for boot screen

Tags: unity, gnome

I was using Ubuntu Unity and today, I tried gnome desktop. However, I didn't like it. Then I removed gnome-desktop and gnome-shell packages. It has successfully removed but still my login screen's splash is the gnome splash.

it was the same for logout (turn off the computer) screen but I've changed it with this command:
`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`
then I selected the Ubuntu's default splash. But it was only affect to the logout screen. My login screen still has the gnome splash logo.

Also, my grub screen's color changed to gray from Ubuntu's default purple color (Canonical Aubergine color).

How can I revert it completely? I've tried all presented solutions on the askubuntu, related to my problem.

**Edit:**
I've found a solution to login screen too!

Here is my commands and outputs:

```
anonymous:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth && sudo update-initramfs -u

  Prefer       Path                                                                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth           100       auto
  1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo-scale-2.plymouth   99        manual
* 2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth           100       manual

My choose: 0
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic
```

The only problem has left behind this solution: grub screen's color. it is still gray.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Solved it by completely purging `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo` and `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text`. This seems to do your edit with the update alternatives as well as restoring the aubergine colour.

Comment: What do you mean by 'purge'? what was your process?

Comment: You know `apt remove`? Well there is an alternative called `apt purge`. It does the same as remove but also gets rid of configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer to the GRUB part of the question because this thread is the top result when googling for a fix, and the GRUB issue seems to be tied to difficulties completely removing the Gnome Desktop. I was able to revert GRUB's background color to the original purple with this command:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop
```